Using analytical concepts to solve the algebraic problem.
Suppose $n\ge 2$. Consider the polynomial $[Q_n(x) = 1-x^n - (1-x)^n .]$
Show that the equation $Q_n(x) = 0$ has only two real roots, namely $0$ and $1$.
I have solve the given problem by showing that $g(x)=0$ for $x=0,1$. And sssuming that it true for $k\in\mathbb N$. And for $x=k+1$ I applied induction and showed that the polynomial has two roots.
But I want a solution which uses the idea of real analysis such that we assume that there is Another real number $\alpha$ in $(0,1)$ which breaks the given Sen into two sets $(0,\alpha)$ and $(\alpha ,1)$ and then the solution proceeds. I did not know and understand the complete idea to do the problem this way, so can anybody show it how to do it using the ideas of real analysis, thank you.

Let's start be evaluating a couple derivatives of $Q_n(x)$ and see if we can find some structure in that we can exploit. The first and second derivatives are
$$Q'_n(x) = -nx^{n-1}+n(1-x)^{n-1}$$
$$ Q''_n(x) = -n(n-1)x^{n-2}-n(n-1)(1-x)^{n-2}=-n(n-1)\left(x^{n-2}+(1-x)^{n-2}\right)$$
From the first derivative, we can note that if $x=1-x$, then $Q'_n(x)=0 \ \forall n\geq2$ . So we might consider dividing our interval up into $x\lt \frac{1}{2}$ and $x>\frac{1}{2}$. In the terms above, we might choose, $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$
From the second derivative, we can see that $\left(x^{n-2}+(1-x)^{n-2}\right)>0 \quad \forall n\geq 2 \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}$, so $Q''_n(x)<0 \quad \forall n\geq 2, \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}$. This means that our first derivative is monotonically decreasing, and combining that with the fact that our first derivative is $0$ at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, we see two cases, which we can consider in turn:
$$\begin{cases} Q'_n(x) > 0 \quad \text{if} \ x\lt \frac{1}{2} \\ Q'_n(x) < 0 \quad \text{if} \ x\gt \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$
For the $Q'_n(x)>0$ case, we see that $Q_n(x)$ is monotonically increasing on the interval $-\infty < x < \frac{1}{2}$, which means any zero crossing is the only zero crossing in this region. From inspection, we see that $x=0$ is a root in this interval, and we know there can be no other roots in this region.
Using a similar argument, we can see that $x=1$ is the only root from $\frac{1}{2} < x < \infty$. Since $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is not a root for any $n\geq 2$, we see that we have found that there are only two real roots of $Q_n(x)$: $0$ and $1$.
